# What is a good example of a hybrid data-set which has over 5000 entries?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a dataset which has the following properties:

- Has more than 5000 entries
- Has both numerical and categorical data
- Is publicly available, free of cost
- I want to test an algorithm, and I have been testing it on the Titanic dataset, but it has too few entries. I am looking for more examples of the same.

As a followup, is there an online resource which keeps tracks of all publicly available datasets with salient details (the type of dataset, number of entries, origin, etc) at one place?

Thank you!

Comment: UCI Machine Learning Repository has datasets that are classified and filterable. You’ll find one there for sure. http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php